# How to read QTextEdit content from another application?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, winapi, spy++

I'm currently trying to make a debugging tool which will sit on top of a proprietary application (which interfaces over BLE with hardware).

Inside of this application (written in QT) there is a text box which has the stream of logging information coming from the hardware, and I want to make an application which will monitor that text box and process the data being logged.

I cracked open Spy++ and found the handles of the window I needed, however, it only displayed as "QWidget" and WM_GETTEXT wasn't pulling any data out. These two links also mention that QT widgets can't be read by the standard Win32 API (which feels strange to me, as I was sure everything needed to pass through the Windows GUI layer):
https://forum.qt.io/topic/36867/accessing-qtextedit-from-another-program/9
https://forum.qt.io/topic/19256/how-get-handle-of-qwidget-child-with-vb-net/9

I'm open to any and all options! I'm language-agnostic on this one. How can I read out the QTextEdit logging data?

Comment: Err... I'm not sure why you would expect to be able to read data out of a Qt Widget implemented by arbitrary code by having access to its window handle.  You might look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/): *"Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code."*  (But I think speaking with the developers of the code to offer some kind of hook is also worthwhile vs. sinking lots of dev time into doing such tasks in a shaky fashion...!)

Comment: Look at this tool - https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt's widgets support *Assistive Technology* (AT) out of the box. On Windows, Qt's [Accessibility](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/accessible.html) is available through [MSAA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971310.aspx) and [IAccessible2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/accessibility/iaccessible2). Either one is capable of inspecting widget trees, and delivering a widget's properties across process boundaries.

Either interface is officially supported by Qt.

Comment: I've seen MSAA mentioned once or twice before, but I haven't seen any examples of it being used for this purpose. I'll dig into this one a bit.. I assume there are a few UI Automation systems built on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't read the content of a `QTextEdit` because it is an alien widget. You can read more in [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) documentation:

> Introduced in Qt 4.4, alien widgets are widgets unknown to the
>   windowing system. They do not have a native window handle associated
>   with them. This feature significantly speeds up widget painting,
>   resizing, and removes flicker.
>
> Should you require the old behavior with native windows, you can
>   choose one of the following options:
>
> 1. Use the QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 in your environment.
> 2. Set the Qt::AA_NativeWindows attribute on your application. All
>      widgets will be native widgets.
> 3. Set the Qt::WA_NativeWindow attribute on widgets: The widget itself
>      and all of its ancestors will become native (unless
>      Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors is set).
> 4. Call QWidget::winId to enforce a native window (this implies 3).
> 5. Set the Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen attribute to enforce a native window
>      (this implies 3).

---

Also there is an introspection tool for Qt which might be of use for you: [GammaRay](http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/gammaray/). Personaly I didn't use it - only read a small overview but it looks promising.

Comment: There is no particular requirement for a widget to be backed by a native window to make it accessible from another process. It only needs to implement the interfaces required to enable [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Which Qt incidentally does for all of its widgets, alien or not.

Comment: @IInspectable, doesn't `Set the Qt::AA_NativeWindows attribute on your application. All widgets will be native widgets` state pretty clearly that all widgets should be native if the attribute set? Maybe not all widgets are backed by the native controls(reality) but the documentation states that they are(theory), as far as I understand it.

Comment: You do not need to fall back to the legacy implementation. Everything the OP needs is available already, as pointed out in my previous comment and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30662529/1889329).

Comment: @ixSci For a start, a change like you propose is highly invasive and the developer might not want to make it, for good reason. Or the asker doesn't have control of the app even to make the change. But the real point is that hacking away with window handles is not the way to perform automation. There's no reason at all for widgets to be windowed and the major UI frameworks of the day use non-windowed widgets. So, use the platform automation facilities as nature intended.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I didn't say it is good nor did I propose to use it. I simply answered the question of why Qt-based application aren't Spyable. Bad or not the possibility to fallback to the native widgets exists and as for me it is good to know about it.

Comment: @IInspectable, I agree that using UI Automation is a better way. I've just pointed to another way to achieve the same. However horrible it might seem it should work.

Comment: @ixSci Thanks for the link and note. I only realized after you wrote it that I had heard about alien widgets back when they were first introduced into QT (years ago). Long since forgotten!

Comment: @SJoshi: Alien widgets were never *introduced*. They were all there was from the get go, until Qt 4 went out on a limb, believing that they (Digia) could do better on their own, and ditched native control implementations. They failed epically.

Comment: @ixSci: You cannot access native controls across privilege levels, when User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) is enabled. UI Automation, on the other hand, can cross privilege levels, provided that the application is digitally signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: @IInspectable, most of the applications are of the same integrity level.

Comment: Uhm... that's an odd statement, assuming you are an engineer. Are you selling your software with a sticker, saying: "Works most of the time!"?

Comment: @IInspectable, who talks about a general tool? The question and most of the questions like this are about the ad hoc tools where target applications are known.

Comment: The target application may be known. But does that imply, that source code and a build environment are available? *"Proprietary application"* sounds like neither is. You are arguing for a solution, that simply isn't. All the less, in face of a [real solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30662529/1889329).